# SQL. Отклонение от предыдущего месяца

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

есть не большая просьба в помоще с работой по дате в PostgreSQL.

Есть запрос:

```
select date,avg(mark) over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as "Среднее",
avg(mark) over(order by date rows between 0 preceding and 2 following)  as "Скользящие среднее"
from markk 
join pupil using(id_pupil)
where id_pupil = 17
```

В чем собственно просьба. Как мне сделать условия: "отклонение от предыдущего месяца" к среднему.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, на примерах данных и/или ссылках, что же такое `отклонение от предыдущего месяца к среднему`

Comment: К примеру, мне сейчас с запроса выдаст результат трех месяцев. В каждом из месяцов мы узнаем среднее. Так вот, мне нужна разница между 1 и 2 месяцем, а 2 и 3 соответственно (в процентах). Это имею введу в выражении: "отклонение от предыдущего месяца"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой запрос выдаст отклонение среднего между предыдущим и текущим месяцем.

```
with t as (
  select date, avg(mark) over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as "Среднее",
  avg(mark) over(order by date rows between 0 preceding and 2 following) as "Скользящее среднее"
  from markk
  join pupil using(id_pupil)
  where id_pupil = 17
)
select date, "Среднее", "Скользящее среднее", 
  ("Среднее" - lag("Среднее") over (order by date)) * 100 / "Среднее" as "Отклонение"
from t
```

Тут [рабочий пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a459e/6) (только для одного студента)

Если нужно что-то немного другое, всё равно, используйте аналогичный подход

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться.